# Simple way to detect encryption

Tags: encryption, detection

Is there a simple and quick way to detect encrypted files? I heard about enthropy calculation, but if I calculate it for every file on a drive, it will take days to detect encryption.

Is it possible to, say it, calculate some value for first 100 bytes or 1024 bytes and then decide? Anyone has a sources for that?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Go through a whole drive and find suspicious files, which may look like encrypted. Tell a user location of these files. Then user can decide what to do, e.g. use some third-party software to decrypt.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a **cross-entropy calculation**. Calculate the cross-entropy value for X bytes for known encrypted data (it should be near 1, regardless of type of encryption, etc) - you may want to avoid file headers and footers as this may contain non-encrypted file meta data.

Calculate the entropy for a file; if it's close to 1, then it's either encrypted or `/dev/random`. If it's quite far away from 1, then it's likely not encrypted. I'm sure you could apply signifance tests to this to get a baseline.

It's about 10 lines of Perl; I can't remember what library is used (although, this may be useful: http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~hammond/ling696f-sp03/addonecross.txt)

Comment: This is an on topic and most correct answer. Interesting would be to know how cross-entropy would behave on compressed data (zip, mp3, mkv) and how it would behave on only the headers (like OP suggested say 1kB of header) - my guess is that entropy will be far from 1 for such headers which would be enough to detect encryption without getting into file format recognition.

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a system that recognizes particular common forms of encrypted files (ex: recognize encrypted zip, rar, vim, gpg, ssl, ecryptfs, and truecrypt).  Any attempt to determine encryption based on the raw data will quickly run into a steganography discussion.

Comment: You are correct about steganography. But your suggested approach will not fight it either. So, to clarify initial question: if we skip steganography question and only fight regular encryption, what is the best approach?

Comment: "Fight regular encryption"?  I thought you only wanted to detect the presence of encrypted data - which is what my answer addresses.

Comment: There is no such thing as "regular" encryption. Besides, in most formats the encryption is embedded in some kind of container format (CMS, XML encryption or proprietary).

Comment: By 'fight' I mean detect. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Here http://www.utica.edu/academic/institutes/ecii/publications/articles/A0B3DC9E-F145-4A89-36F7462B629759FE.pdf I can see some statistical way to detect encryption, but it is based on whole file calculation

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of good encryption is that you can design it so that it *can't be detected* - see the Wikipedia article on [deniable encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption) for example.

Every statistical approach to detect encryption will give you various "false alarms", like
compressed data or random looking data in general.

Imagine I'd write a program that outputs two files: `file1` contains 1024 bit of π and `file2` is an encrypted version of `file1`. If you don't know anything about the contents of `file1` or `file2`, there's no way to distinguish them. In fact, it's quite likely that π contains the contents of `file2` somewhere!

EDIT:

By the way, it's not even working the other way round (detecting unencrypted files). You could write a program that transforms encrypted data to readable english text by assigning words or whole sentences to bits/bytes of it.

Comment: Of course, there is no silver bullet. But how much false alarms you expect comparing to true positives, when using an approach from the article, mentioned in the comment to the first answer?

Comment: Even the article you linked states "may be an encrypted **or** compressed data file" (page 7). There's no way to distinguish compressed and encrypted data other than analyzing known headers/format like Thomas suggested. I'd expect so much false alarms that an "encryption detection" doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Did you even read the cited “deniable encryption” (i.e. plausible deniability) article? The methodology doesn’t prevent the detection of the existence of encryption. Also encoding as words wouldn’t hide the randomness. C.f. also https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17059